# Staggered fade-in divs from 0 opacity

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I have three divs I fade in based on a waypoint on the page. I am trying to stagger these divs. The issue I'm having is because I am fading them in from opacity: 0, once the 'animated' class is added, all the divs display (and then the delayed divs will play their animation from opacity: 1). This is probably a stupid question but I can't think of a way to delay the opacity on the 2nd and 3rd divs without having to give them individual animated classes. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
.project {
  opacity: 0;
}

.project.animated {
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: fadeInDown;
  animation-duration: 1s;

  &:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: .3s;
  }
  &:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: .6s;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInDown {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -40%, 0);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

**Compiled CSS:**

```
.project {
  opacity: 0;
}
.project.animated {
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: fadeInDown;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
.project.animated:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: .3s;
}
.project.animated:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: .6s;
}
@keyframes fadeInDown {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -40%, 0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've edited your question and added the compiled CSS code because not everybody would be familiar with Sass/Less syntax (and it would lead to a lot of comments questioning the syntax, confusions). It is always better to post the compiled CSS unless the problem is with the pre-processor itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Remove the `opacity: 1` from the `.animated` class and add `animation-fill-mode: forwards`. This setting means that the animated element will maintain the state as at its last keyframe (which has the `opacity: 1`) and so there is no need for the extra property setting.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var els = document.querySelectorAll('.project');
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
      els[i].classList.add('animated');
    }
  }, 100);
}
```

```css
.project {
  opacity: 0;
}
.project.animated {
  /*opacity: 1;*/
  animation-name: fadeInDown;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.project.animated:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: .3s;
}
.project.animated:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: .6s;
}
@keyframes fadeInDown {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -40%, 0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: none;
  }
}
/* just for demo */

.project {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
```

```html
<div class='project'>First</div>
<div class='project'>Second</div>
<div class='project'>Third</div>
```

---

**Option 2:**

If for whatever reasons you don't want to remove the `opacity: 1` from the `.animated` class then set the `animation-fill-mode: backwards` to the element. This would make the animated element hold the state mentioned in its first keyframe (`opacity: 0`) during the `animation-delay` period and hence the element would not show up immediately.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var els = document.querySelectorAll('.project');
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
      els[i].classList.add('animated');
    }
  }, 100);
}
```

```css
.project {
  opacity: 0;
}
.project.animated {
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: fadeInDown;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}
.project.animated:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: .3s;
}
.project.animated:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: .6s;
}
@keyframes fadeInDown {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -40%, 0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: none;
  }
}
/* just for demo */

.project {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
```

```html
<div class='project'>First</div>
<div class='project'>Second</div>
<div class='project'>Third</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.project.animated {
  opacity: 1; <- REMOVE THIS
  animation-name: fadeInDown;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  [...]
```

You don't need to specify `opacity: 1;` in the class, the `@keyframes` animation will take care of animating each `<div>` to full opacity.